# Where is toString of Number stored?

Tags: javascript

Some code for example.

```
let a = 1
a.__proto__.toString = function(){ return 'test'}
a.toString()
//"test"
a + '2'
//"12"
```

I realy can't understand where is `toString` method stored.
If I do this with mutable objects I got

```
let o = {}
o.__proto__.toString = function(){ return 'test'}
o.toString()
//"test"
o + '2'
//"test2"
```

That works as I expected.
So the question is where `toString` of `Number` or other immutable types stored and called when type conversion occurs.

Comment: @Ry when `toString` is set that way so is `Number.prototype.toString` is set, I just checked

Comment: [spec link](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1). `toString` and `valueOf` are only called for objects. With `a = 1`, `a` is a primitive value, not an object.

Comment: @niceman: I thought for a bit that the question was what `a.__proto__` was.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> So the question is where toString of Number or other immutable types stored and called when type conversion occurs

It's stored on `Number.prototype`. The more important question is:

> How is a number converted to a string when doing `1 + 'a'`?

Not via the `toString` method!

The `toString` method is only used when converting an object to a primitive value. However, a number is already a primitive value. Instead there is an *internal* `ToString` routine that is called to convert the number to a string. The details can be found in the ES2017 specification at [12.8.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-addition-operator-plus), [7.7.12](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tostring) and [7.1.12.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-tostring-applied-to-the-number-type) . The details are a bit long, but it starts like this:

> 1. If `m` is `NaN`, return the String `"NaN"`.
> 2. If `m` is `+0` or `-0`, return the String `"0"`.
> 3. ...

as you can see, these are very specific instructions for how to convert a number value to a string, which have nothing to do with the actual `toString` method defined on `Number.prototype.toString`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue here isn’t with `Number.prototype`; it’s just that `Number.prototype.toString` isn’t called when converting numbers to strings. JavaScript uses [its internal ToString operation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tostring) for string conversions, and it has special behaviour for primitives.

> Number: Return NumberToString(*argument*).

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't use `toString` to convert primitive data types to string. It [uses its own implementation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-tostring). As a matter of fact, all these examples below follow your example:

```js
let a = 1, b = 'string', c = false, d = 100.5, e = {}
a.__proto__.toString = _ => 'test'
b.__proto__.toString = _ => 'test'
c.__proto__.toString = _ => 'test'
d.__proto__.toString = _ => 'test'
e.__proto__.toString = _ => 'test'

console.log(a + 'X', b + 'X', c + 'X', d + 'X', e + 'X')
```

Answer (score -1):

It's stored as a property of the prototype...

Remember that a number is a number. When you use it to be evaluated in an expression, such as with operator +, its toString method is not invoked. Instead, its value is resolved, and used to evaluate the rest of the expression.